# How do i generate product information report in odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-9

in inventory module I have created some products with locations ,now I want to see the total product information with different url(Ex: 192.168.0.10/product, 192.168.0.10/location)...how do i get the product report...please give me reference for this..

Comment: Better to use Stock Inventory Report app in your odoo app
https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/inventory_report/

Comment: in odoo9 there is no stock inventory report...pls let me know same related module